# Using the Cordova file plugin

Tags: android, cordova, html5-filesystem

In my Android Cordova app I want to serve frequently used image files from a local cache in order to save bandwidth and/or when no network is available.  The [Cordova File plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file) appears to be well suited to this job.  However, I am having some difficulty establishing just how I go about creating cached image files once they have been acquired from an external source.  The steps as far as I can see are the following

- Acquire the external file
- Once it is available use `window.requestFileSystem`to get access to the sandboxed file system.  This returns the file system object which has as its `filesystem`attribute the object `{name:"persistent",rood:DirectoryEntry}
- Pass the directoryentry above along with the acquired image blob to  fs.root.getFile('example.png', {create: true, exclusive: true},fileCreated,fileCreationFailed)
  ...

It is the last step that is not clear to me.  From my reading of the plugin documentation the right location to create the cached image file is  `cache` folder.  However, if I were to issue the above `root.getFile`I would surely be attempting to create the image file in the root folder - which would probably fail because that location is not read-write.

I am either misunderstanding something here or there is a bit of documentation that is missing.  In either case I hope that someone here will be able to put me on the right track.

Comment: Person who voted to close this - could you explain why?  Is my research inadequtae, does the question not suit the format for this forum, am I engaging in self promotion, has it already been answered...?  If you do not say anything and just hit that close button just what purpose do you think it serves?

Answer (score 0):

As [outlined in the cordova-plugin-file documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#create-a-temporary-file) you should be able to use the `window.TEMPORARY` argument when calling `window.requestFileSystem` get to a reference to the application cache folder which you can then use to read/write files:

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
    createFile(fs.root, "newTempFile.txt", false);
}, onErrorLoadFs);
```